# Need to know if transaction is aborting in script

Tags: shell, psql

I've got a shell script that runs an sql file for my database, problem is that when the transaction is aborted for whatever reason (concurrency issue, etc...) I want to know it has failed so that I can do something else, I'm just not entirely sure how I would read from the command that the transaction has been aborted.

'psql returns 0 to the shell if it finished normally, 1 if a fatal error of its own occurs', I want to check for a non-zero code returned.

For example:

```
echo 'Deploying SQL'
psql --quiet --single-transaction --file=myfile.sql
```

The script will be run on a cron so even though it does provide error messages if the transaction is aborted no one will be there to read it everytime, so I need to able to do something when this happens.

For example something like:

```
local result = psql --quiet --single-transaction --file=myfile.sql

if [[ result == 1 ]]; then
   # do something else
else
   echo 'successful'
fi
```

I'm relatively new to shell scripting so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you know the transaction was aborted? Exit code? Output to stderr? Output to log file?

Comment: Should have had that in the question originally, added it in now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the command in an `if-else` statement.

```sh
if psql --quiet --single-transaction --file=myfile.sql; then
    echo 'OK'
else
    echo 'KO'
fi
```

Or check the previous return status via `$?` like this:

```sh
psql --quiet --single-transaction --file=myfile.sql
local result="$?"
if [[ "$result" == 0 ]]; then
    echo 'OK'
else
    echo 'KO'
fi
```